# Can this double inner scroll table be done with CSS only?

Tags: html, css

To better explain the situation. I've made a quick image to explain:

[image]

Basically, this seems paradoxical and I'm not sure if it can be done through CSS only.

The left and right columns can be scrolled vertically at the same time while the header stays fixed on top and NEVER scrolls vertically.

The right column can be scrolled horizontally WHILE also scrolling the left column HEADER horizontally.

Also note, that all this needs to be inside a `<div>` so I can't use `position: sticky`, which only works based on the browser window. The table has a fixed height and the browser window doesn't have a scroll.

Here is my attempt:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.columns {
  width: 796px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: flex;
}

.left-col {
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}

.right-col {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid brown;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.filler-y {
  height: 1200px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

.filler-both {
  width: 2000px;
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="left-col">
    leftcol
    <div class="filler-y"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-col">
    right col
    <div class="filler-both"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6d2a853t/93/)

Comment: If this is a school task, you shouldn't ask for the complete answer here. Try to do it on your own and ask when you got stuck.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. It is expected that you have done sufficient research efford and tried to solve an issue on your own. If you have done that, then present your attempts.

Comment: and yes it can be done. Not even hard. I will give you just one hint: `overflow` + `auto` or `scroll`

Comment: @tacoshy That's what I also thought until i actually tried it. It seems like an easy solution to an easy problem, but in reality it's not. Yes, i've tried all combinations of overflows and visible, hidden, etc. It's not as easy as it seems

Comment: where are you stuck? you are aware that the container needs a fixed width and height to actually overflow?

Comment: yes, the container has a fixed width and height. If you check my jsfiddle you'll see where im stuck.  https://jsfiddle.net/6d2a853t/98/

Comment: I dont understand  your statement about sticky, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: If i understood what you need, unfortunately, the scrollbars will be standing on different structure level, so the horizontal scrollbar won't be seen untill the right box has been scrolled up. You need javascript to create that scrollbar and synchronise it the right box. CSS cannot dissociate the scrollbar from its container.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus That's what i thought. Thank you for the answer and for taking the time to actually understand my problem instead of replying "this is easy, use overflow" like others.